# how can I get the specified content by the string

Tags: sql, oracle

**QUESTION DESCRIPTION:**

My oracle query SQL result have a column, the column value is a string description like as follow.
How can I get the special substring that I want, such as I only want the pilot's name.

```
{"flightRiskValue":{"airportDifficulty":0.00,"airportExp":0.00,"airportExp_captain":0.00,"airportTechNos":0.20,"airportTechNos_captain":0.40,"flightCrewNum":0.00,"flightExp":0.00,"flightExp_captain":0.00,"groupExp":0.70,"ilsWorkStatus":0.00,"pilotCrewLimit":0.00,"pilotCrewLimit_captain":0.00,"pilotDutyLevel":0.05,"pilotDutyLevel_captain":0.05,"pilotFindAnyFemale":0.00,"pilotScheduleTechLevel":0.00,"pilotScheduleTechLevel_captain":0.00,"pilotWorkTimeMonth":0.00,"pilotWorkTimeMonth_captain":0.00,"pilotWorkTimeWeek":0.15,"pilotWorkTimeWeek_captain":0.10,"pilotsIsDeptTeam":0.00,"rain":0.00,"rainAndSnow":0.00,"seeing":0.00,"snow":0.00,"wind":0.00},"pilotDTOList":["副驾驶：5-2|杜佳佳|F3；","副驾驶：5-1|凯尔|F4；","第二机长/巡航机长：5-1|贺云|A1；","机长：5-2|张磊3|A1；"],"riskValue":1.95,"version":"1"}
```

**EXPECTED:**
How can I get the special substring such as follow I want substring:

```
|杜佳佳|,|凯尔|,|贺云|,|张三|
```

and I want a column become more columns according to this column

| first pilot name | second pilot name | .... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 杜佳佳 | 凯尔 | 贺云... |

Answer (score 0):

You can extract each of the items in the JSON array directly into different columns (eliminating the need to `PIVOT`) and then find the substrings (without needing to use [slow] regular expressions):

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(
         pilot1,
         INSTR(pilot1, '|', 1, 1) + 1,
         INSTR(pilot1, '|', 1, 2) - INSTR(pilot1, '|', 1, 1) - 1
       ) AS first_pilot_name,
       SUBSTR(
         pilot2,
         INSTR(pilot2, '|', 1, 1) + 1,
         INSTR(pilot2, '|', 1, 2) - INSTR(pilot2, '|', 1, 1) - 1
       ) AS second_pilot_name,
       SUBSTR(
         pilot3,
         INSTR(pilot3, '|', 1, 1) + 1,
         INSTR(pilot3, '|', 1, 2) - INSTR(pilot3, '|', 1, 1) - 1
       ) AS third_pilot_name,
       SUBSTR(
         pilot4,
         INSTR(pilot4, '|', 1, 1) + 1,
         INSTR(pilot4, '|', 1, 2) - INSTR(pilot4, '|', 1, 1) - 1
       ) AS fourth_pilot_name
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         t.value,
         '$'
         COLUMNS (
           pilot1 NVARCHAR2(200) PATH '$.pilotDTOList[0]',
           pilot2 NVARCHAR2(200) PATH '$.pilotDTOList[1]',
           pilot3 NVARCHAR2(200) PATH '$.pilotDTOList[2]',
           pilot4 NVARCHAR2(200) PATH '$.pilotDTOList[3]'
         )
       ) j
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

> | FIRST_PILOT_NAME | SECOND_PILOT_NAME | THIRD_PILOT_NAME | FOURTH_PILOT_NAME |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 杜佳佳 | 凯尔 | 贺云 | 张磊3 |

*db<>fiddlle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4e6c3f96a174b6bc30cfaa627ded2155)*

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but there the pilots number is dynamic